# loading classes with parent reference in JaxB

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Policy{
    Key key;
    Permissions permissions;
    Policy parent;
    ...
}
```

I also have a policy manager:

```
public PolicyManager{
    Map<Key, Policy> policyMap;

    public Policy getPolicy(Key key){
         return policyMap.get(key);
    }
```

If a policy has a parent it inherits it's parent's permissions.  I'm not committing to actually storing a reference to the parent in each policy, but at minimum I need some way to lookup a parent to inherit it's permissions no matter what the final object's structure.

I'm not certain how to do this when loading a policy with JaxB.  I understand I would probably need to use an XmlAdpter. However, even using the adapter I don't know how I would look up a parent policy.  I don't know any way to inject/pass the policyManager into any of the Jaxb unmarshalling objects, so even if I write my own unmarshaller I don't have a way to look up a parent policy.

The only solution I know of now is to have jaxb return to the PolicyManager some intermediate object and the PolicyManager build an actual policy out of that unmarshalled object.  Is there a 'cleaner' solution then this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` has a `Listener` property allows you to listen before/after object unmarshalling.
Every time you found a Permission in `Listener.afterUnmarshal()` store object somewhere and get it back when you found a `Policy`.